# How can I create a separate search page for my blog?

Tags: search

I made a wordpress blog:  [link text](http://www.myorphan.com/searchblog.htm)

I have a separate htm page with the form and input field to search.  It does not work.  But when I have the search field and submit bitton in the sidebar on every page, it works fine.  I left bot the sidebar search and the "search blog" page available.

Is it possible to have a separate search page and have the results appear normally?

Comment: How wide of a range are you trying to search (just the blog or your whole site)? Are you including Wordpress in your static page? http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Jalenack/Integrating_Wordpress_into_an_Existing_Site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search box is redirecting to the wrong URL

You send the visitor to `/blog/?name=(search term)`

Should be `/blog/?s=(search term)`

You can see this if you look at the URL for a search that works (i.e. from your sidebar).